# why does the following code result in deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have the following class

```
public class LockTester implements Runnable{
 private static Locker locker = new Locker();

 public static void main(String[] args){
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   Thread t = new Thread(new LockTester());
   t.start();
  }
 }

 public void run(){
   for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    locker.unlockFirst();//note unlocking here
    locker.lockFirst();
    locker.lockSecond();
    locker.unlockSecond();
    locker.unlockFirst();
  }
 }
}
```

and Locker class

```
public class Locker{
 private Lock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
 private Lock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

 public void lockFirst(){
  lock1.lock();
 }
 public void lockSecond(){
  lock2.lock();
 }
 public void unlockFirst(){
  if(lock1.tryLock()){//note change
   lock1.unlock();
  }
 }
 public void unlockSecond(){
  lock2.unlock();
 }
}
```

Why does running this code result in deadlock.

Comment: If you remove that first unlock, does it still deadlock?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

lock1 is locked twice: once in `lockFirst` and again in `unlockFirst` (`lock1.tryLock()`), but unlocked only once in `unlockFirst`.

ReentrantLock has a hold count. See [ReentrantLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). If you call tryLock, even if it's already held by the current thread it still increments the hold count. So, you increment it twice, but only decrement it once.

Comment: so do i have to unlock it twice?

Comment: Just remove the if(lock1.tryLock) and the first call to unlockFirst. Do you need it?

Comment: Upvote for "is locked twice." That tryLock() inside the unlockFirst() method is definitely the issue.

Comment: @Tudor: so is there a way to unlock all locks by current thread, or would need to call unlock method multiple times(Ps. i don't need to have the lock.trylock, but was trying out some scenario)

Comment: Well the number 1 and 2 rules of locks are: always unlock in reverse order of locking if you have multiple nested locks and always lock and unlock the same number of times. So the nesting lock1 lock2 unlock2 unlock1 is what you need.

Comment: @Raks It would be a pretty serious design flaw if you found yourself needing to "unlock all locks". Best to follow good practices and prevent deadlocks before they happen. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Having locked `lock1`, you never fully unlock it**. If the thread holds `lock1` when it calls `unlockFirst()`, it will still hold `lock1` when the function returns.

If you call `lock1.lock()` followed by a successful `lock1.tryLock()`, you need to call `lock1.unlock()` **twice** to completely release the lock. Your code doesn't do that, hence the deadlock.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. He *does* unlock it, just not enough times.

Answer (score -2):

You have a static Locker shared across all threads.

At some point a thread is going to try to tryLock() while the lock is already held by another thread.

edit: incorrect, ignore.

Comment: so what? tryLock is designed to handle that.