# C# threading deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multi-threaded program in C#. What is the best way to prevent deadlock in practice?

Is it timedlock?

Also, what is the best tool available to help detect and prevent the deadlock?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There's only one good tool, the one between your ears.  Detecting it is never hard.

Comment: The best way to avoid deadlocks is not to use locks! Failing that, use caution! There are some rules of thumb that moderately help, such as always acquire in the same order.

Comment: [Priority inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion) should also be considered in the design.

Answer (score 2):

Deadlocks typically occur in a few scenarios:

1. You are using several locks and not locking/unlocking them in the correct order. Hence, you may create a situation where a thread holds lock A and needs lock B, and another thread needs lock A and holds lock B. Neither of them can proceed. This is because each thread is locking in a different order.
2. When using a reentrant lock and locking it more times than you are unlocking it. See this related question: [why does the following code result in deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150871/why-does-the-following-code-result-in-deadlock/8150986#8150986)
3. When using `Monitor.Wait/Monitor.Pulse` as a signaling mechanism, but the thread that must call `Wait` does not manage to reach the call by the time the other thread has called `Pulse` and the signal is lost. You can use the `AutoResetEvent` for a persistent signal.
4. You have a worker thread polling a flag to know when to stop. The main thread sets the flag and attempts to join the worker thread, but you forgot to make the flag `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not C# specific. You should always acquired in some well-defined order.
There is much information in internet, for example, you might take a look here
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/deadlock.shtml